# Dimension of subspace orthogonal to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the dimension of a subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, where $V = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ v^T x = 0\}$ for a fixed vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

I've figured out that $V$ indeed satisfies requirements for a vector space, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing down a basis?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that the basis has dimension $n-1$, but I can't generalize my reasoning. If $x = e_1$ is an element of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then all the other elements of the standard basis are orthogonal to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Build a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains $x$. Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove that $\Bbb{R}^n = V \oplus  [x]$, where $[x]$ denotes the subspace generated by $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$.

Therefore, $\dim V = n-1$.